SAML Login with Scala application as SP with pac4j-saml
I have a scala service which would act like the SP and would like to provide users to authenticate using SAML, for which I am using pac4j-saml version 6.0.2. The IdP that I am using is keycloak.
I have a route defined in the routes.scala file
path("login"){
   get {
    complete(StatusCodes.OK -> "OK")
  }
}

I have defined the SAML2Configuration in another class SAMLConfiguration which returns the org.pac4j.core.config.Config object.
class SAMLConfigObject {
  def constructConfigObject: Config = {
     val saml2Configuration = new SAML2Configuration()
     saml2Configuration.setKeystorePath("samlKeystore.jks")
     saml2Configuration.setKeystorePassword("pac4j-demo-passwd")
     saml2Configuration.setPrivateKeyPassword("pac4j-demo-passwd")
     saml2Configuration.setIdentityProviderMetadataPath("http://localhost:9090/realms/IdProvider/protocol/saml/descriptor")
     saml2Configuration.setIdentityProviderEntityId("http://localhost:9090/realms/IdProvider")
     val saml2Client: SAML2Client = new SAML2Client(saml2Configuration)
     saml2Client.setName("SAML2Client")
     val config =  new Config(saml2Client)
     config
  }
}

How do I trigger the login flow when the /login route is being hit.
I might be missing something very basic but any pointers would be very helpful.
Tried following the example in https://cchantep.github.io/akka-pac4j-saml-keycloak-demo/ but that uses a deprecated version of the package.

The code you provided is just an endpoint that always returns 200 without doing nothing else. Could you provide a minimal reproducible example? If you got error messages, add them too

I am not getting any error. My question is what needs to be added to this endpoint such that it triggers the SAML flow. I havent been able to find any related documentation, so posted here to see if I could get any pointers on what needs to be done.
Added the SAML configuration code.

in the trait UserRoutes there are different endpoints defined such as callback, auth/logout, auth/login and users. All of them are invoking different methods from def security: AkkaHttpSecurity (the config for that value lives in QuickstartServer). Not sure if that is enough

I tried that. But that isnt working with pac4j-saml version 6.0.2. The pac4j-saml-opensaml3 being used in that project is also deprecated.

The last commit for that demo was on Apr 28, 2021, the last commit for the lib was on on Oct 26, 2022 and depends on pac4j 4.57. I was able to run the demo locally upgrading to akka 2.9.3 and akka-http 10.6.3 using scala 2.13.14 and JDK 17. If I upgrade pac4j to 5.x.x or 6.x.x it compiles but fails at runtime.

That being said, one option could to fork the akka-http-pac4j lib and upgrade to pac4j 6. If you want to stick to pac4j and use the latest version, there different implementations. Maybe you can consider play-pac4j (compatible with latest version of play and pac4j). Maybe java-saml could work for you
